# How far is Mono with MVC3 and EF Support?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linux, entity-framework, mono

I have a really neat NAS box from QNAP (http://www.qnap.com) and I was just wondering if I can get my MVC3 apps working on it.

I see from the QNAP forums that the latest version will run on a QNAP box (assuming I can figure out the linux commands) but my question is more specific to mono ...

According to http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility there is no support for EF ... do they mean that any code using EF (already compiled) will not run?

This will likely mean my apps wont work on Mono (shame).

There is also no mention of MVC3 on that page which implies they either forgot about it or are saying that the full support for C# 4.0 and ASP.Net 4.0 covers this.

If anyone has any experience with running MVC apps on a linux box can you let me know if any of this possible to get running / workaround please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC 3 works but they don't ship it by default:

[ASP.NET MVC3 Support](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10#ASP.NET_MVC3_Support)

Currently code that uses Entity Framework will not run under Mono. However, Microsoft recently open-sourced Entity Framework and there is now a drive to get it working on Mono. Hopefully it will be done soon:

[Mono 2.11.3 is out](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2012/Aug-13.html)

Comment: Yeh pain or what !!! I also found this: http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA helpful in figuring out what actually is and isn't supported. Wish they would hurry up ... .Net 4.5 will be out soon not to mention MVC 4, the razor 2 engine and likely an update on EF.